# What protocol do car stereos which can interface with iPhones use?

Tags: ios, windows, usb

I would like to write a program which can do the following:
1) Detect when an iPhone or iPod is connected to a computer (Windows, Mac or Linux)
2) Get a list of all of the songs on the device. Title, Artist, Album
3) Make the iPhone/iPod play a particular song.

Basically I would like to write something that mimics what my car stereo can do, but with my home computer via the USB port.

Is that any API to do that?

Comment: When plugging an iDevice into a car, they're probably using something available via [Apple's MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). You'd need to figure out a way to sneak into that licensing program (saying you are writing an "accessory", only here your accessory is really a computer running any OS).